# Is the C preprocessor multi-pass in operation?

Tags: c++, c

I've recently come across the term 'multi-pass compiler'. Essentially, it is any compiler that parses the source code with more than one pass through.

So that got me thinking, is the C pre-processor multi-pass in operation?

Let's say I have the following C code.

```
int bar = foo;

#define foo 1
```

The only possible way this could work in the pass through is if the preprocessor went all the way through the code looking for preprocessor directives, and then went back through the code to make the replacements.

Is this how the preprocessor functions?

Comment: You could, y'know, _test it out._

Comment: @MattBall The question was inspired by a C-like programming language in which the above code is valid.

Comment: There is *rescanning* but that only happens when "recursively" expanding a macro, it never scans further back past the current expansion being processed. So I would not describe it as multipass.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So that got me thinking, is the C pre-processor multi-pass in operation?

It doesn't have to be, and it typically isn't.

```
int bar = foo;

#define foo 1
```

A macro is visible only from the point of its definition (the `#define` line) to the end of the file (or to a corresponding `#undef`). In the above, the first line is *not* replaced by `int bar = 1;`; rather, it remains as `int bar = foo;`, which is valid only if there's already been a declaration of `foo`. (That declaration would be hidden by the `#define`, but only for references *after* the macro definition.)

The behavior of the preprocessor (more precisely, of the first several translation phases) is designed to permit a single pass implementation. See the C standard ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) is the most current draft) section 5.1.1.2 for the specification. The "preprocessor" typically corresponds to phases 1 through 4, or perhaps 1 through 5.

Comment: Ah perfect. I had in mind that the preprocessor was a standard tool, but I assume it can vary based on the environment. I for example have worked with C like languages that contain 'global includes' which must have implemented some type of multi-pass preprocessor.

Comment: The preprocessor is logically part of any C or C++ compiler (it may or may not be implemented as a distinct program). Its behavior is defined by the language standard. Some aspects of its behavior, such as where it looks for headers named in `#include` directives are implementation-defined.